# Navigationbar issue on ios 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios11

[image]

Default backbutton goes down.Please refer any link or solution. How to change that behavior ?

Comment: In above image button does not look like as default

Comment: @NaumanMalik It's default navigation bar back button.But added tint color in previous controller so its looks little different.

Comment: Is your view controller attempting to modify the safeAreaGuide or is the back button a custom class?

Comment: @ekscrypto I did not do any code for backbutton.Just pushing new controller in the stack.

Comment: Did you implement something like `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment`? If yes, then remove it.